# How to find duplicates in two columns access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large table containns 20,000 records. I want to find similar records(duplicate records on those BNO and BNO-CSCcode columns)

```
   CSCcode   Description   BNO        BNO-CSCcode     EID

    05078     blah1        5430      5430-05078       1098
    05026     blah2        5431      5431-05026       1077
    05026     blah3        5431      5431-05026       3011
    04020     blah4        8580      8580-04020       3000
    07620     blah5        7560      7560-07620       7890
    07620     blah6        7560      7560-07620       8560
    05020     blah1        5560      5560-04020       1056
    01234    sampledesc    0009      0009-01234       1156
    04567    sampledesc2   0056      0056-04567       1656
    01234    sampledesc8   0009      0009-01234       0023
```

I want to retrieve like

```
    CSCcode   Description   BNO        BNO-CSCcode     EID

    05026     blah2        5431      5431-05026       1077
    05026     blah3        5431      5431-05026       3011
    07620     blah5        7560      7560-07620       7890
    07620     blah6        7560      7560-07620       8560
    01234    sampledesc    0009      0009-01234       1156
    01234    sampledesc8   0009      0009-01234       0023
```

How do i specify that in sql query.

Comment: There is a wizard to do this in MS Access ( Find Duplicates wizard )

Comment: Yeah, i tried that. But i wonder out of more than 20,000 records it retrive only 4 records. I guess i'm using that wizard wrong may be.How do i use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.* 
from table_name t1
inner join (select BNO,BNO-CSCcode 
           from table_name
           group BNO,BNO-CSCcode
           having count(1)>1) as t2
on t1.BNO=t2.BNO and t1.BNO-CSCcode=t2.BNO-CSCcode
```

Comment: what is t2 or t1 there? I have only one table

Comment: They are alias name for tables

Answer (score 0):

```
  select field1,field2,field3, count(*)
  from table_name
  group by field1,field2,field3
  having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: That's a start, but OP needs needs the that result in a subquery joined to the source table to get the data he needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING:

```
select *
from mytable 
where bno & bno_csccode in
(
  select bno & bno_csccode
  from mytable
  group by bno, bno_csccode
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, my access goes not responding mode, trying to close from task manager. any reason?

Comment: Lack of patience? ;-)

Comment: Because of concatenation no index can be used. That may slow things down. Is the bno always included in the bno csccode? Then simply select the csccodes, i.e. only bno_csccode instead of bno & bno_csccode.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `EXISTS` command in your query.

This will give the desired resuilt:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t0
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName t1
    WHERE t0.BNO = t1.BNO AND t0.BNOCSC = t1.BNOCSC
    GROUP BY BNO, BNOCSC
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
```

`EXISTS` is used for comparison between one or more than one column.